# 1 php page, different contents based on an identifier

Tags: php

I want to make a PHP page that will changing it's content based on some sort of an ID.

The idea is: the index page will have 4 squares, the content of those 4 squares will be the top 4 records in the database, they obviously have their own IDs in the DB.

What I want to happen is when I click on one of the squares it will pass the ID to another PHP page that will get all the details about it in the page.

To be more clear:
Lets say it is a cars website, the 4 squares would be an image of top 4 cars in the database with the IDs 1,2,3 and 4 respectively, when I click on the car's image (lets say 1) I will be directed to a PHP page called `CarInfo.php`

what i want to happen here is for the ID of the square to be passed to this page (maybe page will appear something like `carInfo.php?id=1`) and the page will load all the information from the database where the ID will match the recieved ID (in this case the record with `ID = 1`).

The problem is I don't even know how to start doing it... How can I pass the ID? How can the other page receive it? And can I use a variable to pass it to so I can use it in the query carteria? If so how?

Note: there will be 1 PHP page that displays the information ONLY (aside from index), all content will be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very easy. exactly as you have said. you will use address with parameter, like

```
carInfo.php?id=1
```

and on carinfo page you can use php get variable http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

```
$_GET["id"]
```

it will give you selected id, and you can then use is in database

Comment: i don't get the full idea.. how can i pass it? id is not a variable, it will be part of URL.. how can i save it into the var? or is it that the $_get[""] gets it from URL? a little explanation of the linking process would be wonderful

Comment: $_GET is php variable used to access parameters passed by url. if you will access page by carInfo.php?id=1&foo=9&bar=4 then $_GET["id"] will be 1, $_GET["foo"] will be 9 and $_GET["bar"] will be 4. explanation is on page linked in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the first page you have to do something like this for each car:

`<a href="show.php?id=1">Click Here</a>`

`<a href="show.php?id=2">Click Here</a>`

`<a href="show.php?id=3">Click Here</a>`

`<a href="show.php?id=4">Click Here</a>`

Then, in `show.php` you need to write a code like this to recive information form the provided ID if the database you're using is MySQL:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','USERNAME', 'PASSWORD','DATABASE');
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM YOUR-TABLE WHERE id = '{$_GET["id"]}'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "Color : {$row['color']}";
    // ...
}
?>
```